# Python bluetooth transfer speed?

Tags: python, bluetooth

In Python, am using the LightBlue module for Bluetooth connectivity. How do I get the speed at which I am sending file to my phone from my laptop (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to say "python bluetooth speed", because Python is just a language and an execution runtime and has nothing to do with Bluetooth. You should tell us what Python extension are you using to work with Bluetooth? What bluetooth stack are you using? and eventually the operating system?

With lightblue you can't determine the speed of the connection, because as the project author said it "*provides simple access to Bluetooth operations*", the same with the PyBluez the other Python library for Bluetooth you cannot. Since I guess you are using sockets you could count the sent and received data, so you could have a fair idea.

But to correctly determine the entire input/output traffic quantity you should place yourself inside the stack at HCI layer level and count for:

- ACL - data
- SCO - voice
- Commands
- Events

So my recommendation is to use an already built traffic analyzer like WireShark.

Update:

If you check BlueZ documentation in hci_lib.h there is a function:

```
int hci_devinfo(int dev_id, struct hci_dev_info *di);
```

and the hci_dev_info structure contains the information you're looking for acl_pkts and sco_pkts, so what you should do is to export it in Python this BlueZ API function and use it :)

```
struct hci_dev_info {
uint16_t dev_id;
char     name[8];

bdaddr_t bdaddr;

uint32_t flags;
uint8_t  type;

uint8_t  features[8];

uint32_t pkt_type;
uint32_t link_policy;
uint32_t link_mode;

uint16_t acl_mtu;
uint16_t acl_pkts;
uint16_t sco_mtu;
uint16_t sco_pkts;

struct   hci_dev_stats stat;
};
```

Comment: Come to think about it, this should be a comment.

Comment: I haven't downvote your answer, and sincerely I don't care who downvoted mine too. I am convinced that I gave a correct response, base on the initial question. Hope that it would help Guanidene.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to figure out how large the file is, capture the system time before the transfer and after the transfer, and then do the math. To compute a more fine-grained transfer rate that changes over the course of the transfer, you would need to use the size of your transmit buffers and the time interval between sends.

Comment: Well, I want to know the transfer rate at the time I am sending the file... Not the average transfer rate...

Comment: LightBlue uses a socket interface, right?  You know how many bytes go in each send call and you can determine how much time elapses between each send call.  You can use that information to figure out the transfer rate.

Answer (score -1):

You need a binding for the Bluetooth driver/OS service that handles the Bluetooth device.
Most drivers are written in C, some in C++. If you can get the source code/API or if it's provided you might be able to access it from python. You might need to code some custom binding to your OS service to do so.

Comment: You don't need the source code of a driver/library to use its API. And Guanidene says he already uses a Python library to send the file.

Comment: @RoshOxymoron: He didn't mention it at the time I wrote the question.